# How to run SQL select query via AJAX (live results)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display updated SQL records after using SQL update function. How can I use AJAX to achieve this. In JavaScript file I have SQL update function that works via AJAX. When update function is successfully executed then an Async  function is called. I believe that `data` property is not set properly. After launching this function, no updates are visible until page refresh. I'm trying to get live SQL select output.

**HTML:** (There is included php file: prevoznik.php)

```
<div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-12 ff-nu fs-16 fw-600">Izgled za prevoznika
            <div class="row pt-3" id="prevoznik">
                <div class="col-12 list-widget">
                    <div class="row divider-heading uppercase py-3">
                        <div class="col-1 fs-09 fw-600">id</div>
                        <div class="col-3 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09">naslov</div>
                        <div class="col-1 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09">ura</div>
                    </div>
                    <?php require 'includes/prevoznik.php'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP (prevoznik.php)**

```
$sql3 = "
SELECT id, potnik_id, ura, naslov
FROM prevoznik 
ORDER BY HOUR(ura), MINUTE(ura) ASC;
";
$result = $conn->query($sql3);
$potnik = $row["potnik"];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Spremenjena oblika datuma
        $date = date_create($row["ura"]);
        $ura_pobiranja = date_format($date,"H:i");
        echo "<div class=\"row list  divider-gray\">
                <div class=\"col-1 fs-09 fw-600\">" . $row["id"] . " </div>
                  <div class=\"col-3 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09\">" . $row["naslov"] . " </div>
                <div class=\"col-1 flex-vcenter-items fw-600 fs-09\">$ura_pobiranja</div>
            ";

        if ($row["naslov"] !== null) {
            echo " <div class=\"col-6 flex-vcenter-items fs-1\">
                            <form id='form' action='' method='POST'>
                                 <input id='id' name='potnik' value='".$row["id"]."' type='hidden' /> 
                                 <input id='cas' class=\"form-control fancy-border\" type=\"text\" name=\"posodobljeni_cas\"/>
                                 <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' id='submit' type='submit' value='Nastavi uro'>
                             <label id=\"info\"></label>
                         </form>
                     </div>";
            echo " </div>";//update.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "
        }
        else {
            echo " </div>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<div class=\"col flex-vcenter-items fw-100 fs-1\"><i class=\"far fa-frown-open pr-3\"></i>Nimaš še nobenih opravil
                                    </div>";
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//Async update
    $(function () {
        $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
            let idrow = $("#id").val();
            let updaterow = "update.php?id=";
            console.log(updaterow + idrow);
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: updaterow + idrow,
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    console.log('ura posodobljena');

                    //Async select update
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'prevoznik.php',
                        data: $('.list'),
                        success: function () {
                            console.log('Select izveden');
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

> I believe that data: $('.list') should be replaced, but I don't know what should I insert here.

Comment: `$('.list').html("new content");`

Comment: @u_mulder Insted of "new content", how could i print live SQL select statement. Thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'prevoznik.php',
            data: $('.list')
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log('Select izveden');
            $('.list').append(data)
        });
```

Comment: Seems to be kinda working, but this script loops appends, like multiple repetitions of the whole page happens.

Comment: You can use `.html` instead of `.append` if you want only the last result displayed

Comment: I tried with html and same thing happens. It loops whole website like 100 times. Shoud i change .list to something else?

Comment: `.html` replace the current content of the div by the string you provide. If it's displayed 100 times, it means that you php file is looping 100 times. Is your while loop correct ?

Comment: Yes my while loop is correct. But weird is that loops the whole page instead of looping only SQL select section.

Comment: Not that's perfectly normal. `.html`display the content of everything you printed with `echo` in your PHP file.

Comment: If you want to display only a part of what you printed in your PHP file. You can use the PHP function `json_encode` and then in your `done` function in JavaScript. Parse the result to get a JSON object and then you can write `.html(data.sqlQuery)` for example